# Start Chrome in incognito mode in Ubuntu netboox remix

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) Netbook Remix in my Asus Aspire One. My default browser is Firefox and I am using Chrome for Google search in incognito mode. I want to start Chrome in incognito mode by default. I know that I need to use the following command to start the Chrome in incognito mode by default.

```
Google-chrome  --incognito %s
```

What I do not know is how/where to edit the commandline in the launcher.

Any tips on how to do this is much appreciated.

Edit: This question is no longer relevant. I am using latest version of Ubuntu (12.04) in the same netbook and running chrome in incognito mode after editing the menu.

Comment: Search for the program "Menu Editor". You *should* be able to edit the command there.

Comment: @Rajkumar is this question still valid? Because these versions are probably long gone by now